# iterm2 remove session ended broken pipe alert

Tags: iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Just bought new macbook pro, and just install and setup my development environment, all seems to be working fine, and suddenly, this happen. please take a look a the picture. how do I remove the

```
Session Ended (broken pipe). Restart it?
```

alert box, and continue? I don't have this on my other macbook pro with same scripts, just `oh-my-zsh` and few `iterm2colors/schemes`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What command do you have set in Prefs>Profiles>General>Command? Looks like it's "ssh test" and it can't connect.

Comment: hi, it is blank... I can't remember doing anything other than colors scheme in iterm..

Comment: Maybe your .bashrc or some other login script is doing the ssh?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old but Prefs>Profiles>General>Command cannot be blank if it's selected.

Answer (score -1):

sorry, for late response. I had some sourced scripts into `.zshrc` which had some bugs on it. fixed the scripts, and this problem doesn't happen again. thanks again.

Comment: Can you post your code? otherwise this should be a comment